# How do i access SVG file in angular 5

Tags: typescript, svg, angular5

I have a SVG file, that consists of the Portugal Map, and i want to access that file so i can make the map interactive. Whats the best way to do that?

Here is a snippet oh the svg code:

```
 <path d="m 698.98803,143.04988 -2.24,0.55 -2.05... z"
     title="Lisboa"
     id="PT-11" />
```

Comment: How do you plan to make the map inteactive? By using JavaScript? What features should your map have? Why not using Google Maps?

Comment: yeah maybe using JavaScript and CSS probably yeah... they don't need to have many features, they just need to change color by region and maybe some Mouse Hover effect, i'm not using google maps because i need a vector Map. Does google maps have that?

Comment: something like that https://mapsvg.com/